# How to load all associations across all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple website to learn RoR. It allows users to post reviews for movies, but I want to implement a link in my root view that shows ALL of the reviews in the database. How do I do that?

I want to be able to `<%= link_to 'Reviews', reviews_path %>` but my `reviews#index` URI pattern is `/movies/:movie_id/reviews`

What do I put in my reviews model in order to extract all the reviews in the database?

My reviews controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    @review = @movie.reviews.create(review_params)
    redirect_to movies_path(@movie)
  end

  private
  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:email, :comment)
  end

end
```

Review model:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

And my root view:

```
<h3>All Reviews:</h3>
<!-- put link here -->
<h3>Sort By:</h3>
<p>
    <%= link_to 'Release', movies_path(:sort_param => "release") %>
    <%= link_to 'Title', movies_path(:sort_param => "title") %>
</p>

<h1>Popular Movies</h1>
<% @movies.each do |m| %>
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <%= m.title %>
   <%= m.release %>
   <%= link_to 'Show', movie_path(m) %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781322/how-do-i-render-all-comments-in-a-rails-view) solution but I'm not sure where to put that code. I tried to put it in the Review's index method but I got an error:

```
Couldn't find all Reviews with 'id': (all, {:order=>"created_at DESC", :limit=>10})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **routes.rb**

```
resources :reviews, only: [:index]
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

If you want to display all the reviews from any movie, in most recent order, you could do:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @reviews = Review.order('created_at DESC').limit(10)
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route to `reviews` only in your `routes.rb` file.

```
resources :reviews, only: [:index]
```

Comment: I tried that but now I have two URI patterns associated with reviews#index. `/movies/:movie_id/reviews` and `/reviews` How do I make sure it goes to the right one?